# How do I create an empty game in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm new to Counter Strike, and I'm having a hard time memorizing the map layouts of the different maps.

How can I create an empty game without any bots where I can just walk around and look at the map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select "Offline with Bots" at the main menu, pick the game type. When it comes to selecting the difficulty, the left-most options is for "no bots".

[image]